# Binary Tree Destructor Issue

Tags: c++, debugging, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I have recently been implementing a binary tree in my free-time and I do believe I have it working correctly. However, I have ran into a mysterious segmentation fault when running a simple test. Here is my implementation of the binary search tree:

```
//the binary search tree class
template <class M>
class BS_Tree {
private:
    //node structure
    struct Node {
        M data; //the key of the node
        Node* left,* right,* parent; //node pointers to left right and parent
        Node(M key, Node* p) //parameterized node constructor
            : data(key), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(p) {}
    };
    Node* root; //the root node of the binary search tree
    bool is_left(Node* n) {return n->parent->left == n;} //utility function
    void destroy(Node* n); //used for tree destruction
    void duplicate(Node* const &, Node* &); //used for copy construction
public:
    BS_Tree() {root = nullptr;} //constructor
    ~BS_Tree() {destroy(root);} //destructor
    BS_Tree(const BS_Tree &); //copy constructor
    BS_Tree &operator=(const BS_Tree &); //copy assignment operator
    Node* find(M key); //find function
    void insert(M); //insert function
    void erase(Node*); //erase function
    Node* get_root() {return root;}
};

//destroy function used for tree destruction
template <class M>
void BS_Tree<M>::destroy(Node* n) {
    if(n) { //recursively erase the tree
        if(n->left) destroy(n->left);
        if(n->right) destroy(n->right);
        delete n;
    }
}

//duplicate function used for copy construction
template <class M>
void BS_Tree<M>::duplicate(Node* const &one, Node* &two) {
    if(!one) two = nullptr;
    else { //recursively duplicate the tree
        two = new Node(one->data);
        duplicate(one->left, two->left);
        duplicate(one->right, two->right);
    }
}

//copy constructor
template <class M>
BS_Tree<M>::BS_Tree(const BS_Tree &b) {
    if(!b.root) root = nullptr; //update root
    else duplicate(b.root, this->root); //call duplicate function
}

//copy assignment operator
template <class M>
BS_Tree<M> &BS_Tree<M>::operator=(const BS_Tree &b) {
    if(!b.root) root = nullptr; //update root
    else { //destroy current tree and duplicate source tree
        this->~BS_Tree();
        duplicate(b.root, this->root);
    }
}

//function to find a key and return a pointer
template <class M>
typename BS_Tree<M>::Node* BS_Tree<M>::find(M key) {
    Node* i = root; //create an index
    while(i) {
        //try to find the key
        if (i->data == key) return i;
        if(i->data > key) i = i->left;
        else i = i->right;
    }
    //return a pointer to the key, nullptr if not found
    return i;
}

//function to insert a new node
template <class M>
void BS_Tree<M>::insert(M key) {
    if(!root) { //if no tree, make new node the root
        root = new Node(key, nullptr);
        return;
    }
    Node* i = root; //create an index
    while(true) { //find insertion point and insert new node
        if(i->data > key) {
            if(!i->left) {
                i->left = new Node(key, i);
                return;
            }
            else i = i->left;
        }
        if(i->data <= key) {
            if(!i->right) {
                i->right = new Node(key, i);
                return;
            }
            else i = i->right;
        }
    }
}

//Function to erase a node
template <class M>
void BS_Tree<M>::erase(Node* n) {
    if(n) {
        //no children case
        if(!n->left && !n->right) {
            if(root == n) root = nullptr; //if node is root, make root null
            else { //if node is a child, update parent's children
                if(is_left(n)) n->parent->left = nullptr;
                else n->parent->right = nullptr;
            }
            delete n; //erase the node
            return;
        }
        //one child cases
        if(!n->left) {
            if(n == root){ //if node is root, update root
                root = n->right;
                n->right->parent = nullptr;
            } else { //if node is a child, update parent's children and nodes parent
                if(is_left(n)) n->parent->left = n->right;
                else n->parent->right = n->right;
                n->right->parent = n->parent;
            }
            delete n; //erase the node
            return;
        }
        if(!n->right) {
            if(n == root){ //if node is root, update root
                root = n->left;
                n->left->parent = nullptr;
            } else { //if node is a child, update parent's children and nodes parent
                if(is_left(n)) n->parent->left = n->left;
                else n->parent->right = n->left;
                n->left->parent = n->parent;
            }
            delete n; //erase the node
            return;
        }
        //two children case
        else {
            Node* i = n; //create an index
            i = i->right; //find successor
            while(i->left) i = i->left;
            n->data = i->data; //set nodes data to successor's data
            if(is_left(i)) i->parent->left = i->right; //update successor's parent and its child
            else i->parent->right = i->right;
            if(i->right) i->right->parent = i->parent;
            delete i; //erase successor node
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

As for the test, it is a simple linear vector element insert vs time performance check. It takes a max number of elements and an increment of elements for each test. It then runs the test for each increment and times the insertions. It works fine for the first few iterations (i.e n = 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000), but then I reach a segmentation fault after insertion when the 50000 element tree destructor is called. It is hinting at the line:

```
if(n->right) destroy(n->right);
```

I understand that I am doing an incremental insertion so all of my elements are on the right side of the tree, but I am having a hard time figuring out where I went wrong and why it only messes up on this iteration.

My test implematation:

```
int main(){

//number of elements, max test elements, and test increment
int n, t = 100000, i = 10000;

//run the test a number of times
for(n = i; n <= t; n += i) {

    //get an incremental vector of size n
    std::vector<int> test(n);
    std::iota(std::begin(test), std::end(test), 0);

    //run the insert test print the time interval
    BS_Tree<int> m;
    auto ibs_start = clock();
    for(auto i : test){
        m.insert(i);
    }
    auto ibs_stop = clock();
    std::cout << n << ' ' << (ibs_stop - ibs_start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

If someone could help I would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: Could it simply be my stack overflowing due to the destroy function having to store all of the elements before reaching the bottom and actually deleting anything?

Comment: An unbalanced tree can easily lead to stack overflow. Since you're inserting the elements in order, your tree is in effect a linked list – it only has a right "spine" –  so it's very likely. (If you had a balanced tree, four billion elements would only be 32 levels deep, so it probably wouldn't be a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

If it works for some number of items (40000), but not for a larger, it might be a stackoverflow.  Looking at the code also confirms this: destroying is recursive, and in the case of extremely unbalanced tree, it means as many stack frames as many nodes.

The question is how this could be solved without recursion?  This is not so obvious, as there are two recursive calls.  My solution is to traverse the binary tree, post-order, and delete leaf nodes.

Here is a solution -- an iterative version of the destroy method:

```
//destroy function used for tree destruction
template <class M>
void BS_Tree<M>::destroy(Node* n) {
    if (n) { // iteratively erase the tree
        Node* c = n;  // current node
        while (true) {
            if (c->right) { 
                // it has right child, descend to it
                c = c->right; 
                continue; 
            }
            if (c->left) { 
                // it has left child, descend to it
                c = c->left; 
                continue; 
            }
            // this node has no (more) children, destroy it
            Node* p = c->parent;
            if (p) {
                // update its parent to no longer point to it
                if (p->right == c) p->right = NULL;  // we came from left
                else if (p->left == c) p->left = NULL;  // we came from left
            }
            // destroy the node
            delete c;
            // go back to its parent
            c = p;     
            if (c == n) {
                // where at back at start node, stop
                delete n;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I have tested my solution, and made some small changes.